# How to do a logical operation per instance in a vector of instances

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Say I have a module with inputs of `N` bits and a single bit that I instantiate like so:

```
module foo (
   input wire [N-1:0] x,
   input wire y
);

foo u__foo (
    .x(x),
    .y(x == something)
);
```

And I want to instantiate `M` of them as a vector, and hook up a wire that's `M*N` bits, I know I can do that like so:

```
wire [M*N-1:0] x;

foo u__foo [M-1:0] (
   .x(x)
)
```

But I want to do a logical operation on each `N` bits of the `M*N` wire and hook that up as an input as well, I know I could do it by using a generate statement:

```
genvar i;
generate
    for (i = 0; i < M; i = i + 1) begin
         foo u__foo (
            .x(x[i*N +: N]),
            .y(x[i*N +: N] == something)
         )
    end
endgenerate
```

Or by calculating it in a loop and hooking that up:

```
reg [M-1:0] y;
always @* begin
    for (i = 0; i < M; i = i + 1) begin
        y[i] = x[i*N +: N] == something;
    end
end

foo u__foo [M-1:0] (
   .x(x),
   .y(y)
)
```

I also know I could put a new input and do the comparison inside of `foo` but I can't modify `foo`.

Is there any syntactical sugar that means I can do this a bit more cleanly so I don't need to create a loop and the tool will automatically split the bus and do the operation on every `N` bits? I'm trying to prevent my code from getting unwieldly. If there's a SystemVerilog-only solution, that works too as long as it's synthesizable.

```
foo u_foo [M-1:0] (
    .x(x),
    .y(x[N-1:0] == something)
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the only syntactic sugar that comes to mind in this case is the concat operator `{}` for *something* (or similarly a packed struct).

Answer (score 0):

No. You can manipulate the bit ordering with streaming operators, but I think the `generate` loop is your best option.